# ClassFileTransformer usage in Java

Tags: java, profiling

What is the purpose of java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer in real time. Is this used only during profiling ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is said in the [javadoc API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html) that:

> An agent provides an implementation of this interface in order to transform class files. The transformation occurs before the class is defined by the JVM. Note the term class file is used as defined in the chapter The class File Format of The Java Virtual Machine Specification, to mean a sequence of bytes in class file format, whether or not they reside in a file.

and the class file specification can be found at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/Overview.doc.html#32310

Usually, you don't need `java.lang.instrument.*` package.

Comment: So these classes are not loaded for production environment ?

Comment: they are needed by the JVM internally in order to run your application but you don't need them to implement most of your stuffs. there is no such a thing as production/debugging releases in Java. They are both the same.